# –ldl: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

Пытаюсь создать своё первое окно, но компилятор ругается. Весь интернет перерыл и решения не нашёл. Помогите :D

Компилирую:

```
g++ glad.c main.cpp -lglfw -lGL -lX11 -lpthread -lXrandr -lXi –ldl -o main
```

Результат:

```
g++: error: –ldl: No such file or directory
```

Comment: выглядит, как будто дев пакет для libc не установлен. Какая ось?

Comment: @KoVadim винда. Установил на неё терминал ubuntu

Comment: @KoVadim попробовал `sudo apt install libc-dev-bin`. Не помогло (

Comment: терминал убунту - это wsl? и думаю, нужно устанавливать libc6-dev

Comment: @KoVadim если честно, то я в этом не разбираюсь. устанавливал вот по этому гайду https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJ-Sncozy58. И да `sudo apt install libc6-dev` тоже не помогло

Comment: ой ой. давно такого ужаса не видел. Запустите в консоли где то такую команду `ls /usr/lib*/libdl*a` и посмотрите на вывод. Если вывод пуст, тогда `ls /lib*/libdl*a`. Если и здесь пуст, тогда нужно искать подходящий пакет. А Х сервер установили? Даже если да, у меня есть большие подозрения, что 3d приложения будут через это нормально работать.

Comment: @KoVadim результаты: 1)`ls: cannot access '/usr/lib*/libdl*a': No such file or directory` 2)`ls: cannot access '/lib*/libdl*a': No such file or directory`.  Опять же не знаю что такое x сервер, только начал во всем этом разбираться, но `sudo apt install xorg-dev` и `sudo apt-get  install  x11-xserver-utils` установлены

Comment: я считаю, что лучше либо использовать чистую убунту (даже  в виртуалке) ии использовать glfw в виндовс. А вот такие костыли... не не

Comment: @KoVadim попробовал через чистую ubuntu - результат такой же и проблема никуда не делась

Comment: я бы попробовал для начала запустить `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, а также установить g++.

Comment: @KoVadim я вооообще ничего не понимаю. Вчера вечером покопавшись в чистом линуксе у меня каким-то образом всё получилось. Окошко открылось, и в нём был мой треугольник. Я даже компьютер перезагрузил и попробал заново скомпилировать. Все опять же отлично получилось. Сегодня с утра встаю пробою скомпилировать и опять та же самая проблема `g++: error: –ldl: No such file or directory`.

Comment: очевидно, что завелся барабашка. Открывайте файл с историей (скорее всего это ~/.bash_history) и пытайтесь восстановить хронологию. Чудес не бывает.

Comment: @KoVadim ну что ж , я нашёл причину своих бед. Я просто копировал эти флаги из туториала, а оказывается там перед ldl стоит не минус а как-кто другой знак, тире возможно. Но появился другой вопрос: несмотря на то, что я устанавливал glfw вот так `sudo apt-get install libglfw3`, `sudo apt-get install libglfw3-dev` почему то работает только `-lglfw` а при `-lglfw3` говорит, что `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw3`

Comment: я подумывал о дефисах, но решил, что это уж слишком.

Comment: Дайте вывод команды `whereis libdl`, если не будет что-то похожего, то у вас что-то не так. `libdl: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so`